# Подключение TomCat к IDEA Ultimate 2018.3 (добавление артефакта для диплоя)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, tomcat

Создал maven проект, скачал zip архив tomcat, в IDEA прописал путь к архиву
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь создать артефакт для диплоя, но там только External Source

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Лезу в Projact Structure/Artifacts выбираю Web Application Exploded, жму ok

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По итогу после добавления артефакта, перезагрузки, в меню run, IDEA не видит tomcat ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfFgi.jpg)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас на первом скриншоте список шаблонов, вам нужно создать новую конфигурацию (кнопка `+` в левом верхнем углу настроек)

Comment: Так и есть, поправил, но артефакт все равно не корректно добавляется, папка target не создается, добавил скриншоты.